# how to print the calculated value in r when using text() function

Tags: r, text, scatter-plot

hey I am drawing a scatter plot

```
plot(seq(1:n),x,xlab='Length of Vectors',ylab='Vectors',
type='p',col='black',pch=20,main='Scatter plot of X & Y vectors')

points(x,col='red',type='p',pch=1,cex=2)
points(y,type='p',col='black',pch=20)
points(y,type='p',pch=3,col='blue',cex=2)
text(which.max(x),max(x),'max of x: ',pos=1,cex=0.5)
```

like this beside my points, i want to put a text saying 'max of x: max(x)<-the actual max of x', but since i am using text() function, I have to use '' to write down my text, but I can't figure out how should I put the outcome of max of x as above form.

Comment: Does `text(which.max(x),max(x),paste0('max of x: ',max(x)),pos=1,cex=0.5)` help you? The `paste` function does concatenation.

Comment: yup! this just worked out perfectly! Thanks a lot!